# Postsharp causes error when using Microsoft Report viewer

Tags: c#, reportviewer, postsharp

in my project I use two different versions of MicrosoftReportViewer (Version 9 and 10) and declare them by extern alias.

It seems like PostSharp causes a problem at compiletime that leads to an error at runtime.

Here is the error when I try to show a report:

Method not found: "Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportDataSourceCollection Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.get_DataSources()".

If I deactivate PostSharp for runtime, the error is still there but if I deactivate PostSharp at all, so even for compiling, the report works fine.

Here is how I apply my aspects:

```
[assembly: ClickLogger("Click Events", AttributeTargetMembers = "*Click", AttributePriority = 1)]
[assembly: ParamValueChangedLogger("Value changed events", AttributeTargetMembers = "*ValueChanged", AttributePriority = 1)]
[assembly: ParamValueChangedLogger("Value changed events", AttributeTargetMembers = "*CellValueChanged", AttributeExclude = true, AttributePriority = 2)]
[assembly: CellValueChangedLogger("Cell value changed events", AttributeTargetMembers = "*CellValueChanged", AttributePriority = 1)]
[assembly: DataAdapterLogger("Data Adapter call events", AttributeTargetTypes = "*.Data*", AttributeTargetMembers = "get_Adapter", AttributePriority = 1)]
[assembly: DataAdapterLogger("Data Adapter call events", AttributeTargetMembers = "SaveToDB", AttributeExclude = true, AttributePriority = 2)]
```

Anyone ever had this error or an idea what to do here?

If you need further information feel free to ask.

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Comment: Need more details. What kind of aspect are you creating? How are you applying it? What is it doing? Need code.

Comment: I create OnMethodBoundaryAspects. They all are for logging purposes. I added in my original post how I apply my aspects. The thing is, even if I uncomment all of them the error still appears. The only way to make this error disappear is to really deactivate postSharp so that no code is inserted at compiletime.

Comment: The error you show looks like it's happening on a property getter. Have you tried excluding getter/setters? See my article http://www.sharpcrafters.com/blog/post/Day-3-Applying-Aspects-with-Multicasting-Part-2.aspx or you can also do it using the CompileTimeValidate method http://www.sharpcrafters.com/blog/post/Day-9-Aspect-Lifetime-Scope-Part-1.aspx have you looked into the compiled assembly with ILSpy or dotPeek to see what's actually going on in that getter?

Comment: Report viewer may be trying to find the method via reflection using a string and it's possible that the aspect has changed the name. Use ILSpy to verify what's going on.

Comment: Good morning DustinDavis, I will check this right now. Thanks a lot for your help, I let you know if it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely a bug of PostSharp. The best thing to do is to report it to http://www.sharpcrafters.com/forum and attach a simple project reproducing the issue.

Comment: Yeah I wasn´t able to solve this issue anyway, so I will try to reproduce the error in a simple project. Thanks!